# 'Multiple' values for a variable

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, multiple-records, multiple-return-values

A bit of background. There are multiple tables from multiple databases that have the same schemas. So, when I query to select all columns having the same master code (in the tables, the master code is in the column called CATMASTRCAT), the same code will have multiple rows, the only same thing about them is the CATMASTRCAT column. This works for a single master code (in the script below if I set the variable to 031325-002-70 it will show multiple rows having different organizations and same data with the rest, which is the desired result).

**Question is, is there a way to have multiple master codes be as an input in the variable? I'm planning to create this as a stored procedure.**

This is my  SQL script:

```
DECLARE @ProductNumber AS VARCHAR(1000)
SET @ProductNumber = ('031325-002-70')

SELECT ITEMS
    ,ORGANIZATION
FROM [EU].[dbo].[SOMETHING14]
WHERE ITEMS in (@ProductNumber)

UNION

SELECT ITEMS
    ,ORGANIZATION
FROM [EU].[dbo].[SOMETHING12]
WHERE ITEMS in (@ProductNumber)


UNION

SELECT ITEMS
    ,ORGANIZATION
FROM [EU].[dbo].[SOMETHING11]
WHERE ITEMS IN (@ProductNumber)
```

Feel free to clarify any other needed data. I'm fairly new to SQL, just self-learning. You can also lecture me about the wrong code haha and how to do this better.

Thanks!

P.S. [Attached the picture of query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj9LE.jpg)

Comment: You should take a look at table valued parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Where are the multiple master codes coming from? Are you going to type them in in SSMS, are they coming from an application, if so what type of application? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: (Also, is the thing you're really trying to do is query `AJF` and `AJN` with _multiple_ master codes each, or are you trying to simplify the code so one master code can query both `AJF` and `AJN` (and others, presumably) without duplicating the same code? And are you sure you need `UNION` there? Usually `UNION ALL` is all that's required, and it's faster, too.)

Comment: I will edit the question, will paste my full code and the query result as well

The SQL Server version is MS SSMS 18.9.2

Comment: SSMS and the sql engine are different applications. What is the result of select @@version?

Comment: I edited the question, and attached the picture as discussed

Answer (score 1):

Yes the best way to do this is to use a table value parameter and then change the where clause to say

```
WHERE catmastrcat IN (SELECT catmastrcat FROM @tablevaluename)
```

or you could use an inner join -- which might be faster depending on indexes and other issues - the code for that would look like this

```
JOIN @tablevaluename tv ON AJF_CATMASTER.catmastrcat = tv.catmastrcat
```

Comment: Good answer. Might be worth showing how to declare and insert into a table variable also (OP seems to be using SSMS)

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm really stupid in this stuff as of now haha would gladly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Ceejay -- google is your friend - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16